# Why can IntelliJ IDEA resolve the classes but Groovy / Griffon cannot?

Tags: import, intellij-idea, classpath, griffon, dcm4che

I'm working on a Griffon app, using IntelliJ, and I'm trying to use the dcm4che project libraries. I've managed to get IntelliJ's code editor to stop complaining about missing classes, but when I go to run the Griffon app, the compiler goes down in flames, complaining that it is `unable to resolve class DicomInputStream`, etc.

I'm not doing anything fancy. All I'm doing is trying to include a few simple jar files, but for whatever reason, things are not working correctly.

I admit, I'm not particularly well versed in dealing with classpath issues, and I've only been using IntelliJ for a little while, and Griffon / Groovy for even less time, but I'm completely stumped.

Here's the set of import statements that fail:

```
import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream
import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject
import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomElement
```

And this is the set of error messages I get in the IntelliJ console when I try to run or debug the app:

```
Base Directory: C:\Users\[REDACTED]\MyApp\MyAppClient
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 698ms.
Running script C:\Program Files (x86)\Griffon\Griffon-0.9.4\scripts\RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
 [griffonc] Compiling 32 source files to C:\Users\[REDACTED]\.griffon\0.9.4\projects\MyApp\classes
 [griffonc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
 [griffonc] C:\Users\[REDACTED]\MyApp\MyAppClient\griffon-app\controllers\myappclient\SelectRootController.groovy: 9: unable to resolve class org.dcm4che2.data.DicomElement
 [griffonc]  @ line 9, column 1.
 [griffonc]    import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomElement
 [griffonc]    ^
 [griffonc] 
 [griffonc] C:\Users\[REDACTED]\MyApp\MyAppClient\griffon-app\controllers\myappclient\SelectRootController.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream
 [griffonc]  @ line 7, column 1.
 [griffonc]    import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream
 [griffonc]    ^
 [griffonc] 
 [griffonc] C:\Users\[REDACTED]\MyApp\MyAppClient\griffon-app\controllers\myappclient\SelectRootController.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject
 [griffonc]  @ line 8, column 1.
 [griffonc]    import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject
 [griffonc]    ^
 [griffonc] 
 [griffonc] 3 errors
Compilation error: Compilation Failed
```

To install the dcm4che libraries, I did the following:

1. Download the [library binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/dcm4che2/2.0.25/) (the -bin zip) and unpack the zip to `MyApp\MyAppClient\lib\dcm4che-2.0.25-bin`
2. In the Project Structure dialog, under Modules->MyAppClient, under the Dependencies tab, I  click "Add" and select the folder: `MyAppClient\lib\dcm4che-2.0.25-bin\dcm4che-2.0.25\lib`

At this point, the code editor stops complaining about not being able to find and resolve the classes, but when I run or debug the application, I get the compilation errors. Everything works *just fine* without importing those classes (and the code that uses them).

What can I do to resolve this? What other info would be helpful to figure out what is going on?

Comment: How exactly did you tell IDEA where your dependencies are? AFAIK the orthodox way is to either put them into lib directory, or use a special DSL to point to them via Maven ids.

Comment: @PeterGromov, I added a description of how I added the libraries. Based on the console output with and without those imports, the Java call isn't changing at all (like, to add the directory to the classpath)

Comment: Please try putting the jar directly under the MyAppClient\lib.

Comment: @PeterGromov, Putting all of the jar files in the `lib` directory works, but if I put them inside any directory therein, like `lib/dcm4che/`, the IDE can find them, no problem, but Griffon cannot. Is there something that can be done to fix this? I'd really hate to have to have _all_ of my jar files in one massive directory with no organization, especially when multiple projects need the same things.

Comment: That's how Griffon works, sorry. You could try managing dependencies via DSL (http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/0.9.4/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.4%20Dependency%20Resolution) but be aware that IDEA doesn't currently support that (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-6134), and you'll have to manage the module dependencies manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Peter suggests, either you configure the library as a dependency using the dependency DSL (if it's available from a maven or ivy repo) or place it inside MyApp/lib (no additional sub directories). Those are the conventions set by Griffon.

Comment: It would be _great_ if Griffon could more easily handle having more organization in the `MyApp/lib` directory.

Comment: That's why we have the dependency DSL in the first place. However we might supported nested dependencies inside $app/lib after Griffon goes 1.0.